# Change Slider image during sliding in Cocos-2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I wish to use a slider in Cocos-2d-x where when you slide it, a new sprite image should be shown which shows the value of the slider.
I mean as we increase the slider value the width of this image increases and vice versa.

Is there any in-build function for this.

Comment: setScaleX will just increse the width... i wish to know if there is something in-build which will show another image for slided part (value of slider).

Comment: you means a clipping node? I guess you need use something like glScissor. there is no default ones.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but there is something similar in my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giggleup.TC1AFree Under the settings, there is a sliding menu, I am not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: What you can do is play around with callback functions using setScale as @m.ding suggested and try to setDisplayFrame of your sprite to show new sprite image